# Google Scripts getValue / setValues

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get that `getValue` returns a two dimensional array, I'm just too new at this script to make what I want to work.

I want to add a value to each row in column A (the row number less 1). What I've tried is:

```
/*
ttWS.getRange(2,1,100,1).setValue(ss.getActiveCell().getRow()-1);
This worked well, but gave 0 as the answer to every row, understandably. 
*/
  
ttWS.getRange(2,1,100,2).setValues(ss.getActiveCell().getRow()-1);
```

So how do I use a 2 dimensional array in one column OR what other way would you get a calculated value into each row of column A?

Comment: getValue() returns a single value getValues() returns a 2d array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addValueToColA() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().map(r => [i + 1]);
  sh.getRange(2,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, Much appreciated. I now get a column of the sane value, which is a step forward.
However, what I want in col A is the row number - 1. I've adapted your code to

function addValueToColA() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Timetable");
  var value = ss.getActiveCell().getRow()-1;
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().map(r => [r[0] + value]);
  sh.getRange(2,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
But am still getting the same value in each row of the column.
Obviously missing the obvious somewhere